# getting error IndexError: bytearray index out of range PIL

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library, indexoutofrangeexception

I get error when running my code after I changed my image style.

Before that the image was working fine with my code.

here is my code:

```py
def fixedBW(RGB):
    return RGB[0]

def BW8(RGB):
    return round(RGB[0] / (255 / 8))

bits = 8

ATable = ['.','*','|','/','(','&','O','%']

filen = input('file: ')

im = Image.open(filen)

im2 = im.convert('P')
im2.save('8-bit.png')


pix = im.load()
pix2 = im2.load()

for x in range(im.size[0]):
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        im.putpixel((x, y), (pix2[x,y],pix2[x,y],pix2[x,y]))

im.save('8-bit-BW.png')

pixels = []

for x in range(im.size[0]):
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        #print(BW8(pix[x,y]))
        pixels.append(ATable[BW8(pix[x,y])])
    pixels.append('\n')
        
#print(pixels)
finpixs = ""
for x in range(len(pixels)):
    finpixs = finpixs + pixels[x]
#print(finpixs)

ASCIItxt = open(filen + '.txt', 'w+')
ASCIItxt.write(finpixs)
print('Wrote ' + str(len(finpixs)) + ' chars to ' + filen + '.txt')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    im.putpixel((x, y), (pix2[x,y],pix2[x,y],pix2[x,y]))
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1743, in putpixel
    value = self.palette.getcolor(value)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImagePalette.py", line 110, in getcolor
    self.palette[index + 512] = color[2]
IndexError: bytearray index out of range
```

this happend when i changed my image it was a X white shape with some colors around it, it worked then random colors mixed then a stickman that didn't work i got this error. Also image size was always 32x32

thank you for readng

Comment: Could you please provide the image, which leads the mentioned error? Is it a grayscale image (or any other than a RGB image)? Feeding such an image to your code, I get a different error, but the same line is affected. Since you have three values in your `putpixel(...)` call, this will crash if `im` has mode `L` (grayscale) for example. You could enforce RGB mode for your inputs by using `im = Image.open(filen).convert('RGB')`.

Comment: im2 = im.convert('P')  ----> im2 is a palettizzed RGB with just one channel, try im.putpixel((x, y), (pix2[x],pix2[x],pix2[x])) or im.putpixel((x, y), (pix2[y],pix2[y],pix2[y])) and tell us how it goes